# SML : Replacing a concat by printing the string directly

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sml, smlnj

I've got a function which is correctly working for now... 
But which is unfortunately constructing a very big string before displaying it.

I would like to display every string directly instead of concatening them but I don't know how to do it...

Here is the function:

```
fun getBlocked w =
    case BlockingMgr.listBlockedSuccessors w
    of nil => ""
    |  ws  =>
        concat (
            List.map (
                fn (r, w') => ( 
                   " v " ^ r ^ 
                   " w " ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w ) ^ 
                   " w"  ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w') ^ "\n" 
            ) ws
        )
```

This function is concatenating all the `w'`possible and then:

```
fun af w = print( getBlocked(w) )
```

With `af` I'm able to display one node. And then in the final code I'm calling

```
app af ( Nodestore.listNodes() )
```

And my function `app` will call `af` on all the `Node` of my `listNodes()`.

So as I said, this code is working but when the list start to be huge, it is not usable anymore... My guess is that the `concat` is definitely not a good idea, so I would like to replace it and be able to display directly each `w'` successor of each `w`. But unfortunately, I'm quite a newbie in SML and I don't know how to do it...

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you really want, but from what I understand, the following should solve your problem:

```
fun displayBlocked w =
  let
    fun renderW (r, w') =
      " v " ^ r ^
      " w " ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w ) ^
      " w"  ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w') ^ "\n"
  in
    case BlockingMgr.listBlockedSuccessors w
    of nil => ()
    |  ws  => List.app (fn w => print (renderW w)) ws
  end
```

With display count:

```
fun displayBlocked w =
  let
    fun renderW (r, w') =
      " v " ^ r ^
      " w " ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w ) ^
      " w"  ^ Int.toString (Node.getId w') ^ "\n"

    fun renderAndInc (w, count) =
      (
        print (renderW w);
        count + 1
      )
  in
    case BlockingMgr.listBlockedSuccessors w
    of nil => 0
    |  ws  => List.foldl renderAndInc 0 ws
  end
```

Comment: Thanks ! *--* that's exactly what I want :) 

I just need now a function from what you wrote which is giving me the number of time that we call 'renderW' and I will solve fully my problem :) 

Any idea how I could do this ? 
If not never mind, you already done a lot I will manage from this :)

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail I've added a version for that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems very nice :) but I need first to know how many it will be and then I need to display it :/ 

And in this code it's doing both in the same time :/ and I don't really know how I can access this `count` :/

Comment: @ValentinMontmirail `List.length` gives you the size of a list. Use that before iterating over `ws`.